# Redis: How to set expire for updating list

Tags: redis

I want to store in Redis a set of uncertain length and the whole set should expire after a few minutes.

So, I'm doing:

```bash
RPUSH 'a' 'b'  
EXPIRE 'a' 120  
RPUSH 'a' 'c'  
EXPIRE 'a' 120
```

but in this case i have only 'c' in 'a', because the first RPUSH after EXPIRE desroys the old value.
Setting EXPIRE first, we have TTL->-1 after first RPUSH.

So my question, is there the way to do that i want?

Comment: Can't reproduce. RPUSH works correctly for me.

Comment: What is the your result for LRANGE 'a' 0 1 for example above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the first RPUSH after EXPIRE desroys the old value

This is not the behavior or Redis. Are you sure LIST `a` hasn't simply expired already when you add `c` to it? I did a quick check using `redis-cli` and confirmed Redis behaves exactly how you want it to using your approach:

```
RPUSH test foo
EXPIRE test 120
RPUSH test bar
EXPIRE test 120
LRANGE test 0 -1
# 1) "foo"
# 2) "bar"
```

Calling EXPIRE properly resets the expiration, so it gets extended by 120 seconds. Any changes to the list do not impact the expiration or existing values.

Comment: my "not so good" hoster has installed the ancient version: 1.2. with the current vesrion is everything fine. thx!